# How to avoid getting "sudo: Account or password is expired, reset your password and try again"

Tags: linux, root, group, useradd

I am trying to add user e.g. `amit` to group amit,as below.

```
root# groupadd -g 1500 -f amit                              
root# useradd amit -m -G sudo -u 1500 -g 1500 -o -p "amit"
```

However, when I try to switch to user `amit` it gives out the message as below:

```
root# sudo su - amit
sudo: Account or password is expired, reset your password and try again
Changing password for root.
```

May I please know, why am I getting this message, what should I do in order to avoid getting this message and get directly switched to `amit` user.

Comment: There are some settings that enforces new password after some definite interval. Also sudo deprecated some old hashing algorithms and if you are still using them, it will prompt to change. Maybe, it is either of two.

Comment: You don't need to call `sudo` if you are already root

Answer (score -1):

The manpage for `useradd` states that the password supplied should be encrypted. `"amit"` is definitely not. Therefore as the `password` is corrupted, it will force you to change it. You really do not want to supply a password, even when encrypted, as it will be shown via both `ps` and through the `history` command. Always run `passwd <userid>` so it is hidden.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but this should be a comment. « the password is corrupted, it will force you to change it » => this is not standard behavior, who is "it", what system are you referring to? How could user 1500's password affect `sudo` here, which is run by root? Are you stating that this password is corrupting the *whole* `passwd` file??? I'm not even sure a password field made of 4 alpha characters is considered "corrupted".